# 32Bit 3rd party modules in 64Bit apache

Tags: apache-http-server

I hv got a 32bit module for apache server, but it server was upgraded to 64bit which is not able to load the module.
Anyone got an idea or workaround to load 32bit modules in 64bit apache? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You will need to either run a 32-bit build of Apache or obtain 64-bit versions of those modules.